# Accessing state in functional component after redirect

Tags: reactjs, url, redirect, state, prop

After returning a `<Redirect>` to another functional component I do not seem to be able to access the `carId` property in the component to which I was redirected. I'd like to know if anyone has solved this problem in the past.

The redirect would contain a pathname "..\cars\cardetail\carId" and would additionally contain a state property: `"state:{carId:xxx}"`. However, although I am redirected to the correct page, I do not seem to be able to pull the carId off either the Url or out of the state object.

Comment: can you post the code you tried ? a minimal example on sandbox would be much better?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<Redirect>` use

```
props.history.push({
    pathname: '..\cars\cardetail',
    state: {carId:xxx},          
  });
```

If you get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" try the following.

Due to recent changes now route props are not being passed implicitly. So use "useHistory" hook

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory();

history.push({
  pathname: '..\cars\cardetail',
  state: {carId:xxx},          
});
```